# Why /. pm->\[PlusMinus] does not work, if \[PlusMinus] does not have internal meaning?

Tags: pattern-matching, output-formatting, named-characters

I want to replace `pm` with PlusMinus character in the output, why this does not work? How can I treat it as a constant?

Context. Here is my code for quaternion algebra:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ  Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Tr[x]/Length[x];
Matrix /: Conjugate[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[-x] + 2 Re[Matrix[x]]
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_ ?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];

$Post = FullSimplify[# /. i -> Matrix[( {
               {I, 0},
               {0, -I}
              } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
              {0, 1},
              {-1, 0}
             } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
             {0, I},
             {I, 0}
            } ) ] /. 
        f_[Matrix[mat_], args___] :> 
         Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[#, args] &, mat]] /. 
       Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
        Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k ] &;
```

And I want to add a rule

```
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := 
  1/2 (Matrix[x . y] + Matrix[y . x]) ± 1/2 (Matrix[x . y] - Matrix[y . x]);
```

Unfortunately, replacing plusminus with a 2-component list or interval object does not work.

Comment: ``\[PlusMinus]`` is not a regular symbol, but an operator for [`PlusMinus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlusMinus.html). Therefore, you can replace ``/. pm -> PlusMinus`` (although I think this is probably not what you _actually_ want). Perhaps this: ``a pm b /. x_ pm y_ :> x \[PlusMinus] y``?

Comment: @Domen `a pm b` would be considered by the system as multiplication, but I want Mathematica to act on `pm` as either 1 or -1 in rewriting.

Comment: Just checking, you are not trying to reproduce the functionality of `Around[x,δ]`, are you?

Comment: @Anixx, what is the initial expression in which you want to make the replacement? How is `pm` represented if not as a multiplication (or addition) with something?

Comment: @Domen added context

Comment: @rhermans I have added context. Interestingly, `Around` kinda works but the output is not the best. For `i j` I get the output $0\color{grey}{\pm -k}$ with symbols after 0 are smaller, greyed out and not copyable. The desired output is $\pm k$

Comment: @Anixx, where did the symbol ``pm`` now go? You can use ``\[PlusMinus]`` with your ``Matrix``, evaluate ``$Post =.; Matrix[Array[a, {3, 3}]] \[PlusMinus] Matrix[Array[b, {3, 3}]]`` and it will work just fine. However, you have some complicate ``$Post`` which messes things up.